# How to customize CoveoSimpleFilter to single select dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, coveo

I have a requirement to develop a single select filterby dropdown using Coveo framework. Coveo provides CoveoSimpleFilter which is multi-select. How to customize CoveoSimpleFilter to single select dropdown.

```
<div class="CoveoSimpleFilter"
   data-title="All Filters"
   data-field="@somevalue"
   data-enable-clear-button="true">
</div>

//this is my code for dropdown
function Dropdown() {
    $('.CoveoSimpleFilter').click(function (e) {
           
            $('.coveo-simplefilter-value-container').toggle();
        });

        $(document).on("click", function (event) {
            if ($('.coveo-simplefilter-value-container-expanded').is(':visible')) {
                $('.coveo-simplefilter-value-container-expanded').hide();
            }
        });

        // Drop down select
        $('.coveo-simplefilter-value-container-expanded .coveo-checkbox-label').click(function (e) {
  
            $('.coveo-simplefilter-value-container-expanded').hide();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: I have added the code but I am not able to override the default JS of CoveoSimpleFilter